# Monotone function and the limits

Tags: calculus, limits

This may be an elementary question, but it's been a while since I took calculus in high school.

Suppose $f(n)$ is monotone, and I am given that:

$$\tag{1}\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}[\log n-f(n)-\log f(n)]=c_1$$
$$\tag{2}\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}[\log n-f(n)-\log f(n)]=c_2$$
where $-\infty<c_1\leq c_2<\infty$.

Does this imply the existence of a limit?

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}[\log n-f(n)-\log f(n)]=c_1=c_2$$

Another way of phrasing this question would be, if I am given (1) and (2), and $f(n)$ monotone, then does necessarily $c_1=c_2$?

Comment: If the limit exists then $c=c_1=c_2$ .... so then the assumption that $c_1< c_2$ is inappropriate, i would write $\le$

Comment: But I am wondering if I can say that the limit exists?  Even though $f(n)$ is monotone, $\log n-f(n)-\log f(n)$ may not be...

Comment: That the real question.. but I'm just saying you should consider editing to reflect this fact (if it exists). I'd edit it but because I'm not the author i can't because the change doesn't require too many characters.

Comment: Yes, I understand your point and I edited the question.

Comment: $\{x_n\}$ in $[−\infty,\infty]$ converges if and only if $$\lim\inf_{n\to\infty} x_n = \lim\sup_{n\to\infty} x_n.$$

Comment: Okay... I'd still delete the very last thing  before the question or mark. Net, is n an integer, or any positive real number , or what?

Comment: @mathlove Yes, I understand that.  However, is it implied by what I am given that $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ must necessarily be the same? Squirtle, good point, I changed that.  And $f$ takes real input, so $n$ is a real number (which is growing large).

Comment: @HellRazor: It's a good question. So far, I can't say anything.

Comment: So, the point is the case $c_1\not=c_2$, right? I think your 'edited' question still has a bit strange point. You don't need to write as $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\cdots)=c_1=c_2.$ It's better to write just as 'Does this imply the existence of the following limit? $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\cdots)$ Because this value may be equal to neither $c_1$ nor $c_2$?

Comment: @mathlove Well, that's what I had prior to editing the question.  Perhaps it better phrased with bounds on $\liminf$ and $\limsup$: imagine having an oracle that, when asked about this function $f(n)$ tells you that it's monotone, and that the $\liminf$ in (1) is bounded from below by $c_1$ and the $\limsup$ in (2) is bounded from above by $c_2$. I am now trying to figure out whether the limit exists.  Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle \ln{n} - (f(n) + \ln{f(n)}) = \ln{(\frac{n}{f(n)e^{f(n)}})}$.

When $n = 2^k$, choose $f(n)$ such that $\displaystyle \frac{n}{f(n)e^{f(n)}}$ is nearly 1.  This ensures that the inf limit is at most zero. Keeping $f(n)$ constant between successive powers of $2$ will make the sup limit at least $\ln{2}$. So there are monotonic $f$'s for which the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Nice answer!  I think the example you gave also works if $f(n)$ is strictly monotonic (just need to grow $f(n)$ slowly between successive powers of 2) and continuous (put in smooth transitions that do not follow Lambert W between successive powers of 2).

Comment: Yes, that is right.